# How to get foreign key reference with Derby JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, derby

I have tables created with

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRY (NAME CHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE PERSON (NAME CAHR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
       CITIZENSHIP CHAR(16) CONSTRAINT CY_FK REFERENCES COUNTRY (NAME))
```

So how can I get Table.Column (`COUNTRY.NAME`) reference of the foreign key after I've performed `SELECT` query on `PERSON` table?
Is it possible to do via JDBC *ResultSet*, *ResultSetMetaData* or something alike?
In fact, I need to know:

- either column has a *Foreign Key* constraint;
- list of constraint values.

Well, I did `SELECT` on `SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS` but there are only types of constraints ('P', 'F', etc) but no *Referenced Tables'* names.

#### Update

I send queries to the *Database* via *JDBC*

```
PreparedStatement stmtDerbyDb = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectString).prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM \"" + dbTableOrView + "\"");
ResultSet rsltDerbyDb = stmtDerbyDb.executeQuery();
ResultSetMetaData rsmdDerbyDb = rsltDerbyDb.getMetaData();
...
```

All the variables *stmtDerbyDb*, *rsltDerbyDb*, *rsmdDerbyDb* are used in further code. I need to know: is it possible to fetch Foreign Key constraints from *dbTableOrView* via JDBC or shall I query `SYS.*` system tables somehow?

Comment: why do you need `country.name` since the query `select name,country from person` itself returns the country name ?

Comment: Ah, disambiguation. Let me correct the question a bit

Comment: Ok, now column name is `CITIZENSHIP` and if I do `SELECT NAME, CITIZENSHIP FROM PERSON` - I'll get only those values that are stored in `PERSON` not in `COUNTRY` but I need all possible values from `COUNTRY` (application does not know the name of referenced table yet neither does about referenced coulumn name).

Comment: What do you mean with "*after I have performed SELECT*" - why do you need the FK constraints after a select?

Comment: See _Update_ to the question, hope it will clarify some points.

Comment: I think you are looking for [getExportedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (although I still don't understand why this would be needed to run a select)

Comment: Thanks for hint, I'll try this. As for run select... Emm. I thought of two variants: either I can get **all constraint values** via JDBC API or I have to query `SYS.*` tables in order to get the values.

Comment: [DatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is the stuff to get all foreign keys' references (Primary/Unique constraint keys). It seems that I still have to select that Primary/Unique Keys.

Answer (score 0):

Possible decision:

```
...
Connection connTableView = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:Derby:database_name:create=false");
DatabaseMetaData dbmdTableView = connTableView.getMetaData();
ResultSet rsltTableConstraints = dbmdTableView.getImportedKeys(null, null, "PERSON");
PreparedStatement prstTableContents = connTableView.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM PERSON");
ResultSet rsltTableContents = prstTableContents.executeQuery();
...
buildTableView(rsltTableContents);
rsltTableContents.close();
...
while (rsltTableConstraints.next()) {
    PreparedStatement prstConstraints = connTableView.prepareStatement("SELECT " + rsltTableConstraints.getString("PKCOLUMN_NAME") + " FROM " + rsltTableConstraints.getString("PKTABLE_NAME"));
    ResultSet rsltConstraintsForCol = prstConstraints.execute();
    ...
    setColumnConstraints(rsltConstraintsForCol, rsltTableConstraints.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"));
    ...
    rsltConstraintForCol.close();
    prstConstraints.close();
}
...
```

Which is supposed to be used as `ComboBox` dropdowns with constraints per column (with FK of course).

Comment: so you found a soultion ?

Comment: I hope it is (the solution) 'cause I don't see any better way to set up constraints on columns other than quering referenced tables. But it is an answer on how to get _Foreign Key_ references with JDBC (and it does work with Apache Derby).