# How do I get a list of the foreign keys in a derby database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to ensure a foreign key has been created in my derby database and the first step is to check to see if the foreign key exists and applies to the correct columns.

I have been examining system tables like sys.sysforeignkeys and sys.sysconstraints, but while I have chased the ids from table to table through various sys* tables, I can't seem to figure out how to map a row in sys.sysforeignkeys into the column names.

What SQL query would I have to perform to check if the following ALTER TABLE has already been performed?

```
ALTER TABLE ClipPoints ADD FOREIGN KEY(clipName) REFERENCES LABELS(label)
```

This needs to be a fully automated process without user intervention.

Comment: `SYSFOREIGNKEYS.CONGLOMERATEID` references an index. I guess you need to join that to `SYSCONGLOMERATES`

Comment: That is one of the references I chased.  The conglomerates table has columns SCHEMAID TABLEID CONGLOMERATENUMBER CONGLOMERATENAME ISINDEX DESCRIPTOR ISCONSTRAINT CONGLOMERATEID and none of those lead me to a column name either.

Comment: As you are using Java anyway, why don't you use `DatabaseMeta.getImportedKeys()`?

Comment: getImportedKeys() appears to have no rows.  getExportedKeys() appears to show the info I need.

Comment: I always forget in which direction those two methods "point" ;)

Comment: For an example with some code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781458/how-to-get-foreign-key-reference-with-derby-jdbc?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using the dictionary views:

Here's how you can query the foreign keys in Derby:

```sql
SELECT
  fc.constraintname,
  ft.tablename,
  fs.schemaname,
  fg.descriptor,
  pc.constraintname,
  ps.schemaname
FROM sys.sysconstraints fc
JOIN sys.sysforeignkeys f ON f.constraintid = fc.constraintid
JOIN sys.sysconglomerates fg ON fg.conglomerateid = f.conglomerateid
JOIN sys.systables ft ON ft.tableid = fg.tableid
JOIN sys.sysschemas fs ON ft.schemaid = fs.schemaid
JOIN sys.sysconstraints pc ON pc.constraintid = f.keyconstraintid
JOIN sys.sysschemas ps ON pc.schemaid = ps.schemaid
WHERE fc.type = 'F'
```

The table that you've been missing is the `sys.sysconglomerates` table. It contains a "descriptor" that looks like this:

```
DESCRIPTOR
----------
BTREE (1)
```

Unfortunately, it's a bit tricky to decode that descriptor into column indexes with SQL, so you might need to resort to Java in order to find the relevant column(s).

#### Using JDBC `DatabaseMetaData`

In the case of Derby, it's probably more reasonable to use the JDBC standard `DatabaseMetaData` API, which is implemented by the Derby JDBC driver:

```java
try (ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getImportedKeys(null, null, "CLIPPOINTS")) {

    while (rs.next()) {
         System.out.println(
             "  FK_NAME = " + rs.getString("FK_NAME")
           + ", FKTABLE_NAME = " + rs.getString("FKTABLE_NAME")
           + ", FKCOLUMN_NAME = " + rs.getString("FKCOLUMN_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Comment: the javadoc says its FKTABLE_NAME.  is FK_NAME a working alias?

Comment: @MutantBob: I guess I forgot to add `FKTABLE_NAME`. But you wanted to look for the foreign key itself, and I thought that `FK_NAME` would do the trick for you. Check out [all of the columns in the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just dump the schema with [dblook](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/tools/ctoolsdblook.html) and then just go look at the foreign key section of the schema.

e.g.

```
-- FOREIGN
ALTER TABLE "LINE_ITEM" ADD CONSTRAINT "LINE_ITEM_SALE_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SALE_ID") 
REFERENCES "SALE" ("ID") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
...
```